# How to make a query to return the number of rows grouped by day?

Tags: mysql

I am using this expression:

```
SELECT DATE(calldate) as Data,COUNT(clid) as Registros,dst as Tronco
FROM cdr WHERE dst=55008133070000 
AND calldate BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-15'
GROUP BY DATE(calldate), clid HAVING COUNT(clid) > 1 ORDER BY Data DESC

Date---------Total------ Trunk
2012-10-11  3   55008133070000
2012-10-11  2   55008133070000
2012-10-11  3   55008133070000
2012-10-10  2   55008133070000
2012-10-10  2   55008133070000
2012-10-10  2   55008133070000
2012-10-09  3   55008133070000
2012-10-09  2   55008133070000
2012-10-09  2   55008133070000
2012-10-09  3   55008133070000
2012-10-09  5   55008133070000
2012-10-09  5   55008133070000
```

However, needs to be shown the amount of times that day repeated.

```
Date---------Total------ Trunk
2012-10-11  3   55008133070000
2012-10-10  3   55008133070000
2012-10-09  6   55008133070000
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED** due OP comment:

You should group by `dst` and not by `clid`, also count for distinct destination number, see GROUP BY clause and COUNT:

```
SELECT DATE(calldate) as Data,COUNT( distinct clid) as Registros, dst as Tronco
FROM cdr 
WHERE dst=55008133070000 
      AND calldate BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-15'
GROUP BY DATE(calldate),  dst 
HAVING COUNT(distinct clid) > 1 ORDER BY Data DESC
```

Comment: I already grouped by dst however returns the total calls, I need only the amount that a number of different phone made ​​the call.

example

If the phone number of "A" made ​​2 calls on 16.10.2012 and phone number "B" held over 6 calls, I need to show that two phone numbers performed more than 1 call.

thanks for your example however it returns the grand total, not respecting the CLID> 1

Answer (score 2):

In your query, you're using `GROUP BY DATE(calldate), clid` which will give you the `COUNT()` for each `clid` on each day.

Remove the `clid` from the `GROUP BY` clause to get a count for each date.

Your final query would look similar to:

```
SELECT
    DATE(calldate) as Data, COUNT(*) as Registros, dst as Tronco
FROM
    cdr
WHERE
    dst=55008133070000 
    AND calldate BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-15'
GROUP BY
    DATE(calldate)
HAVING
    COUNT(clid) > 1
ORDER BY
    Data DESC
```

In this query, however, pulling `dst` may not make sense and could be removed.

Comment: I already grouped by dst however returns the total calls, I need only the amount that a number of different phone made ​​the call. example If the phone number of "A" made ​​2 calls on 16.10.2012 and phone number "B" held over 6 calls, I need to show that two phone numbers performed more than 1 call. thanks for your example however it returns the grand total, not respecting the CLID > 1

Comment: the syntax is not respecting the CLID> 1, is displaying only the total daily

Comment: @user1753403 I'm not sure what you're asking for at this point. I made a sample schema and executed my query-above and it produced the exact output you requested: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a974/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Id, do using Calldate.

```
SELECT DATE(calldate) as Data,COUNT(calldate) as Registros,dst as Tronco
FROM cdr WHERE dst=55008133070000 
AND calldate BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-15'
GROUP BY DATE(calldate), dst HAVING COUNT(calldate) > 1 ORDER BY Data DESC
```

Comment: I already grouped by dst however returns the total calls, I need only the amount that a number of different phone made ​​the call. example If the phone number of "A" made ​​2 calls on 16.10.2012 and phone number "B" held over 6 calls, I need to show that two phone numbers performed more than 1 call. thanks for your example however it returns the grand total, not respecting the CLID> 1